# I don't understand why I'm having problems comparing strings in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, compare

I'm trying to create a simple program that allows the user to add any amount of numbers they want, and then get the total. However I'm having some problems, I think with string comparison.

```
#!/bin/sh

total=0
decision="y"
echo "please enter a number >"
read number
total=$(($total+$number))
while [[$decision == "y"]]
do
    echo "would you like to add another number? Type y for yes and n for no >"
    read decision
if [$decision == "y"]
then
    echo "please enter a number >"
    read number 
    total=$(($total+$number))
else
    echo "your total is:"
fi
done
echo $total
```

The terminal says I'm having problems on line 8, the     while [[$decision == "y"]] line.

Whats wrong with my comparisons?

Comment: paste your code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ It contains many errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[` is actually an shell command. As such you need a space after it.

Comment: that's sorted it, thanks!